# Specify which compiler to use for GCC build while configuring

Tags: gcc

What option should be provided to `configure` in order to specify with which compiler the build should be carried out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `CC` environment variable to specify the C compiler, and `CXX` to specify the C++ compiler.